# Disable `use safari suggested password` without disabling autofill

Tags: macos, safari, password

Is there a way to disable "use safari suggested password" shown below, without disabling autofill? [image: use safari suggested password]

Comment: Just start typing instead, it will vanish.

Comment: @Tetsujin while that works, I was wonder if there is a way to disable it since I never use it

Comment: This misbehavior makes it very problematic to use my third-party password manager to create and store passwords.

Comment: Agreed, frequently it overwrites the generated password I just got from 1Password with its suggestion, which is infuriating.

Comment: For those who navigate primarily by keyboard, the escape key dismisses the jarring prompt.

Answer (score 32):

The correct answer is: there is no way to disable the suggested passwords "feature" without completely disabling auto-fill.

Comment: I wish this was not the answer.

Comment: https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

Answer (score 3):

At least as of MacOS Ventura, it is possible to selectively turn off password suggestions without completely turning off autofill:

Safari > Settings > Passwords > Autofill > [unselect "User names and passwords"]

[image: Screen grab of unselecting "User names and passwords"]

Answer (score -13):

Safari->preferences->passwords, delete those you do not want.

Comment: The question isn't about auto-filling existing passwords, it's about automatically creating new passwords.